# A segmentation fault (core dumped) in producer and consumer using semaphore

Tags: c, linux, consumer, producer

I am learning Linux system programming, so I just tried to code a very common program which is producer and consumer. I used the semaphore mechanism to implement my code. Unfortunately, I got a **segmentation fault** which I really could not find where I was wrong. I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Code as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sem_consumer;
sem_t sem_producer;

typedef struct node
{   
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node * head = NULL;

void * producer(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem_producer);
        Node *ptr = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        ptr->data = rand() % 1000;
        printf("++++++ producer: %lu, %d\n", pthread_self(), ptr->data);
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
        sem_post(&sem_consumer);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void * consumer(void * arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem_consumer);
        Node *pdel = head;
        head = head -> next;
        printf("------ consumer: %lu, %d\n", pthread_self(), pdel->data);
        free(pdel);
        sem_post(&sem_producer);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sem_init(&sem_consumer, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_producer, 0, 3);

    pthread_t pthid[2];

    pthread_create(&pthid[0], NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pthid[1], NULL, consumer, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(pthid[i], NULL);
    }

    sem_destroy(&sem_consumer);
    sem_destroy(&sem_producer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: run in gdb may be and then bt

Comment: For these kinds of bug, use a sanitzier (in this case, the [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html))

Comment: Note also that `printf()` statements such as `printf("------ consumer: %lu, %d\n", pthread_self(), pdel->data);` aren't guaranteed to be emitted atomically, so you're likely also to get interleaved output if your code runs threads simultaneously.  Your posted code isn't supposed to run the producer and consumer threads simultaneously so that won't become apparent.

Comment: Not the cause of your problems, but you shouldn't call printf inside a semaphore lock, that's gonna be horribly inefficient. Instead grab the semaphore, copy the relevant part to a local variable, release semaphore, print local variable.

Comment: @Lundin you are right, I will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
sem_init(&sem_producer, 0, 3);
```

initializes the `sem_producer` semaphore to 3, allowing the producer and consumer threads simultaneous access to code such as

```
ptr->next = head;
head = ptr;
```

and

```
Node *pdel = head;
head = head -> next;
printf("------ consumer: %lu, %d\n", pthread_self(), pdel->data);
free(pdel);
```

Your linked list isn't properly protected by the semaphore. That's a race condition.

Initializing `sem_producer` to 1 will correct the race condition:

```
sem_init(&sem_producer, 0, 1);
```

There may be other errors that I haven't identified.

Comment: @hellow If you're going to change the meaning of an answer, please comment on why.  I haven't analyzed the OP's code enough to state that initializing the semaphore with a value of 1 instead of 3 will produce correct results.

Comment: ... are you sure? `sem_init(&sem_producer, 0, 3);` will allow `producer()` to loop three times... isn't the issue more about protecting one resource (`head`) with two semaphores?

Comment: @Attie And that looping will happen simultaneously with the consumer thread also modifying the linked list.  I haven't analyzed the code enough to determine what happens once it gets into that state.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Race Condition, I got it.  So how can I avoid this, I mean that what should I do to max the buffer for producer safely, because I don't want the semaphore just have only one.

Comment: Yes, but at that point it'll be a list of one (why not just have a pointer). Which _presumably_ isn't what OP wants from such a proof-of-concept.. (_I presume_)

Comment: @AndrewHenle To be fair: if you aren't sure if your answer is correct, you shouldn't post an answer, but instead a brief comment. However, it seems quite likely that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @attie Maybe, maybe not.  I believe the producer can *stay* up to three iterations ahead of the consumer, and both will be modifying the list at the same time, although I haven't really analyzed the code enough to be sure.

Comment: @Lundin This was definitely an error that could lead to the observed `SEGV` failure, and therefore **an** answer.  I'm just not sure it's the **only** answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point, there could be more problems. You should rollback the edit.

Comment: @Melvin *So how can I avoid this, I mean that what should I do to max the buffer for producer safely*  You could use a mutex on the portions of the threads that access the linked list, eliminate the producer semaphore, and use just the consumer semaphore to tell the consumer thread there's at least one element in the linked list to operate on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle good solution, I just forgot that I should use a lock to protect the critical zone.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is:

- You have one resource - `head`
- Your're "*protecting*" it with two separate semaphores - `sem_producer` and `sem_consumer`

Semaphores are used to signal "*you can take something*", or "*you may put something*", controlling the resource usage - for example if you want to ensure that the list never gets deeper than three objects. This is especially important when the producer / consumer threads have different execution times. If you're not overly fussed about producing loads of items that the consumer may never keep up with, then you can remove the `sem_producer` entirely.

Mutexes ("*mutual exclusion*") are used to ensure that two threads don't handle one object at the same time. I'd suggest you use a mutex around the pointer manipulation along side the semaphores.

```c
pthread_mutex_t mux;
```

```c
void *producer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&sem_producer);

        /* gather data */

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
        p_new->next = head;
        head = p_new;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);

        sem_post(&sem_consumer);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

```c
void *consumer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&sem_consumer);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
        p_next = head;
        if (p_next != NULL) {
            head = p_next->next;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);

        /* skip if there isn't actually a new item */
        if (p_next != NULL) {
            /* do processing and discard */
        }

        sem_post(&sem_producer);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Don't forget to call `pthread_mutex_init()` and `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.

Comment: As currently posted, if `pdel` is `NULL` and the producer thread is waiting on the `sem_producer` semaphore, the threads will deadlock.  With a mutex in place, it's logically safe to eliminate the `sem_producer` semaphore entirely.  In reality, if the producer thread gets too far ahead, the max possible semaphore value might come into play.

Comment: @Attie I think if statement after pthread_mutex_unlock method in consumer is no need at all, because I have the sem_consumer semaphore to ensure that I have item definitely when sem_wait nonblocked. And you had missed freeing the pdel in consumer.

Comment: "_I think if statement after pthread_mutex_unlock method in consumer is no need at all_" - possibly, but if you entertain the "_what if_" scenario, then having the test it will prevent your application from crashing... `sem_wait()` can return for reasons aside from "_you got a poke_".

Comment: "_you had missed freeing the pdel in consumer_" - I removed the memory management from my example code... there should be lots more return value checking too!... omitted for brevity :-)